# Error compiling app after upgrade Android Studio 3.5 to 3.6.1

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-architecture-navigation

I'm getting this error, my I got no idea what else to do.

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'app-name'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-generator:[2.2.0].
 Required by:
     project : > androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.2.0
  > Failed to list versions for androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-generator.
     > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-safe-args-generator/maven-metadata.xml.
        > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/navigation-safe-args-generator/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

I've tried Invalidate and restart, delete .gradle and .idea folder

Now my Android Studio is 3.6.1 and gradle-wrapper : gradle-5.6.4-all.zip

This is my `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }


}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.2.0"
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The navigation related in app `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

// Navigation framework
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:$verNavigation"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$verNavigation"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$verNavigation"
```

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to the latest [version](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation)? 2.3.0-alpha04

Comment: Tried also with 2.2.1 but still the same. Then I try comment out regarding safeargs, then alot of others implementation shows error.

Comment: Is your application developed in Kotlin or Java? Because I see you have a varying number of dependencies

Comment: Kotlin. It's okay, now working. As per the error "Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway", now I'm able to access the link in web. My application also able to run with no problem. Been troubleshooting for hours on this. Wasted my time, I thought it was because Android Studio upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was due to "Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway" to Maven directory. After lunch time, it was working fine.

Prior to that I couldn't open the link inside the error message.

Wasted hours of my time today to troubleshoot this, as I had just updated my Android Studio to new version. Thought this was what caused the issue.

Hope someone would find this useful in future. LOL